# Why can I not combine two partitions into one from Disk Management?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

Okay I have 3 partition, both on the same hard drive, one is OS, the other 2 are for data. I want to combine the 2 data partition into one, How can I do that?

If I go to Disk management, when I right click the volume the "Extend Volume ... " option is grey out (both of them) I can only shrink or delete the volume.

Help ! Thanks!

Note: running in Windows 7

Comment: I'd add that you only want free programs into your question, then.  Last time I went looking for apps that let you "merge" partitions like you want, Partition Magic was the only tool that let you do it, paid or otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move all of the files from one of your data partitions to the other.
In disk management, delete the now-empty partition.
You should then be able to grow the remaining partition to fill the empty space.

If that doesn't work, move all the data files off the system (onto an external USB drive, for instance), delete BOTH data partitions, and create a new partition that fills the now-empty space.

Comment: okay well the problem is that both partition are kind full, and have a large number of files, it takes hrs to transfer to an external USB and copy it back. Prefer if there is any other options.

Comment: Well, you don't really have any other options. I believe that there is no free tool that will combine live filesystems and leave the contents intact. I'm not even sure Partition Magic (a non-free tool) can do that. Combining two filesystems without losing any data along the way is pretty difficult to get exactly right. Even if there were a free solution, you'd need to back everything up first, because any bug could destroy all your data.

Comment: It's better for it to take hours to save your data onto a USB Drive and have a backup than try something which will merge but has a high probability of destroying both partitions. 

When I mess around on my computer I save all my files to an external USB drive, yes it take a long time but in the end if what I tried doesn't work I still have my data.

Comment: Partition Magic can do that, my friend.  I've done it.

Comment: Well, now we know. He needs to backup first anyway, but it's good to know. Can the latest PM work with Win 7 drives?

Comment: @ Mike - See, that's what I'm not sure about.  My guess is that it should work just fine, as long as filesystem driver code hasn't changed too much in Windows 7.

Comment: Yuk. I just checked the Wikipedia entry. Apparently Symantec hasn't updated the thing in years, and it had crash problems with Vista formatted partitions. No mention of Win 7, but I'd bet that it's no good. Too bad, I bought a copy from PowerQuest years ago and it was rock solid at the time. Sad to see Symantec letting it go to bit rot.

Comment: @ Mike, after perusing some forums a bit more, the likelihood of it working reliably doesn't seem like a sure thing to me.  The last version of Partition Magic available predates Vista's release.  While this doesn't mean it won't work, it's very unclear if it would.  The OP is probably better off following your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a (rather slick) tool called [Partition Magic](http://www.symantec.com/norton/partitionmagic) to solve that problem, although I'm not sure if that will work with Windows 7 or your partitions, esp. if Windows7 uses a different filesystem format.

Comment: well its a paid program and for one thing, Windows 7 uses the same file system NTFS. I'm looking for a way to solve this without using those paid programs.

Answer (score 0):

[How to Resize Partitions in Windows 7](http://www.killertechtips.com/2009/05/05/how-to-resize-partitions-in-windows-7/)

delete (backup first!) the 2 'data' partitions, then use **Extend Volume ...** on drive C: and set it to the maximum availabe size.

note: backup your system before messing with partitions!