# How to combine two partitions in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backup, partitioning

I have a laptop with a 500 GB hard drive, running Windows 7 64-bit. The hard drive is partitioned as follows:

- C - 58 GB
- D - 136 GB
- E - 136 GB
- F - 133 GB.

C is my primary partition, where I've installed the OS. Now I need to combine my D and E partitions, without re-installing my OS. I might be able to take backups for D and E, so the data on those partitions won't be a problem.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Back up, only delete E partition, then extend D into the old E partition which is now unallocated. This should save you from copying some data back.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/30211/108226

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your OS is on partition C you should do the following to combine D and E:

1. Back up all data from drive E (e.g. external hard drive or D partition if there is enough free space).
2. Use Disk Management Snap-in from the Microsoft Management Console (mmc.exe) to delete partitions E.
3. Extend partition D using the unallocated space created from the actions in step 2.
4. Copy the data back to the larger partition if necessary.

Comment: Don't even need to delete D:, can just delete E: and extend D: into the now unallocated space.

Comment: Yes you are right. I will edit appropriately. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this, is with the freeware Easeus Partition Manager.

You can download it here: http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm

The Home Edition (which is free) offerrs enough features.
It's has no spyware or adaware and i use it several times for repartitioning hard disks.

Even if you would resize your main boot partition (where windows is installed) Easeus will do this with ease.

As Mike recommends, it's always recommended to make backups of your partitions before.
But my experience with Easeus is that it works flawlessly.

Also the handling is very easy. Just move some sliders, press the apply button and let Easeus do the rest for you. You don't have to worry about moving files from one to another partition or about unallocated space...